# Is there any new information on the YouTube HTML5 video format?

Tags: youtube, firefox, html5

I remember somewhat recently that YouTube was using the [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) codec for their videos in HTML5 format. This is a proprietary format, and Firefox is open source, so they only support [Theora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theora) and [Ogg Vorbis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis).

Does YouTube plan on supporting Firefox (or does the Firefox developers plan on using H.264?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube are also supporting the WebM format which will be supported under Firefox version 4.

> Supported Browsers
>
> We support browsers that support both the video tag in HTML5 and either the h.264 video codec or the WebM format (with VP8 codec). These include:
>
> Firefox 4 (WebM, Beta available here)
> Google Chrome (h.264 supported now, WebM enabled version available via Early Release Channel)
> Opera 10.6+ (WebM, Available here)
> Apple Safari (h.264, version 4+)
> Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 (h.264, Beta available here)
> Microsoft Internet Explorer 6, 7 or 8 with Google Chrome Frame installed (Get Google Chrome Frame)

Taken from http://www.youtube.com/html5